# DXA java setup configuration in Headless environment?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

Question 1:
Can we in the integration layer (DXA Java application) take the topology domain(Base Url) from the browser URL(Angular Website), instead of the proxy URL(DXA Integration layer configured domainin webserver) , as per below examples:
For abc.com:
https://www.abc.com/content/group?format=compactjson  We use the following proxy:
location /content/ {
proxy_pass http://abccom-integration-layer-master:8086/;
}
The domain in IL is http://abccom-integration-layer-master:8086/ , we would like it to be https://www.abc.com/ ( as in user browser ) instead.

For https://market.abc.com/content/nl/nl?format=compactjson We use following proxy:
location /content/ {
proxy_pass http://abccom-integration-layer-market-master:8086/;
}
The domain in IL is http://abccom-integration-layer-market-master:8086/ , we would like it to be https://market.abc.com/  ( as in user browser ) instead.

Question 2:
Is it possible in integration layer and Tridion topology to do a mapping on star so that for example *.abc.com domain is mapped to a [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) topology ?

Comment: I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around what you are asking for, exactly. Can you elaborate?  What is "the integration layer"?  What is "the topology domain"? What is "a www.abc.com" topology?

Comment: On Q1 - if you’re passing through several layers of proxy - does the end listener know what was in the browser in the first place (e.g consistently passed through in headers?)

Comment: Updated my post to explain integration layer and topology, hope I gave clear explanation

Comment: This sounds like an issue in your proxy server? "proxy_pass" looks like NGINX - I'm pretty sure NGINX can pass the original request URL though to your integration layer via a X-Forwarded-Host header for example.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: You need to adjust the headers to be forwarded from the origin in your proxy server, per Neil's suggestion. That should take care of the origin header.

Question 2: TopMan would only allow well-formed URLs to be part of your base URLs. wildcards are not considered to be well-formed.